# draw box in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-animate, line

I am trying to animate the drawing of a box that will then fill in when it is complete. I am taking a class in JS so the code has to be JS. The problem is that the right side of the box will not animate correctly. If I put in one set of coordinates for it it animates from the bottom to the top instead of from the corner where the top line started. When I reverse the coordinates it does animate from the proper corner but instead of drawing the line it starts with a solid line and takes away from it, like a disappearing line. Also both the left and right side lines seem to go off the area assigned. For example my area is 600 x 400 and the lines go off the bottom of the page. If I change the dimensions to 600 x 600 the lines still go off the page. The point of this whole project is that we have coded houses using the SVG library and I want to create an animation to make it look as though the house is being drawn before it fills in the colors. This is more for my own knowledge as it is no longer an assignment. There are 2 links to my jsfiddle, the first one is going to be the problem code of drawing the box. The second is what the house that I would like to animate is to look like.

[drawing box](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesta1972/3c4dyh0m/)

```
    "use strict"
    var draw = SVG('drawing').size(600, 400);

    function makeBox()

    {
    var line1 = draw.line(25,175,26,175);
    line1.stroke({width:1});
    line1.animate(4000).size(550);

    var line2 = draw.line(575,175,575,176);
    line2.stroke({width:1});
    line2.animate({duration:4000,delay:4000}).size(200).move(575,375);


    var line3 = draw.line(575,375,574,375);
    line3.stroke({width:1});
    line3.animate({duration:4000,delay:8000}).move(25,375).size(550);

    var line4 = draw.line(25,375,25,374);
    line4.stroke({width:1});
    line4.animate({duration:4000,delay:12000}).size(200).move(25,175);
    }
    makeBox();


    function makeBaseb1(bx,by,c,s)

    {
    var Baseb1 = draw.rect(550,200).opacity(0).fill(c).stroke();
    Baseb1.animate({delay:'16s'}).opacity(1).fill({color:c});
    Baseb1.stroke({width:s,color:'black'});
    Baseb1.move(bx,by);

    }
    makeBaseb1(25,175,'#FF9900',1);
```

[house](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesta1972/ajsa7nav/)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with the `makeBox` function:

- The `.size` method taks 2 arguments instead of 1 (`x` and `y` dimension).
- For the line drawing in the reverse direction wrt the coordinate system,
  both, starting coordinates and line length, need to be animated.

The updated function:

```
function makeBox() {
    var line1 = draw.line(25,175,26,175);
    line1.stroke({width:1});
    line1.animate(4000).size(550,0);

    var line2 = draw.line(575,175,575,176);
    line2.stroke({width:1});
    line2.animate({duration:4000,delay:4000}).size(0,200); 

    var line3 = draw.line(574,375,575,375);
    line3.stroke({width:1});
    line3
        .animate({duration:4000,delay:8000})
        .during(
            function (pos, morph, eased, situation) {
                line3.x(morph(574,25));
                line3.size(morph(1,550),morph(0,0));
            }
         )
    ;

    var line4 = draw.line(25,374,25,375);
    line4.stroke({width:1});
    line4
        .animate({duration:4000,delay:12000})
        .during(
            function (pos, morph, eased, situation) {
                line4.y(morph(374,175));
                line4.size(morph(0,0),morph(1,200));
            }
         )
    ;
}
```

The use of the `.during` method is documented [here](http://svgjs.com/animating/#during-duringall).

Comment: OMG, thank you so much. I had asked 2 teachers and 2 TA's what might be wrong with the coding. They couldn't see anything that would make it run the way it was. I was told to just forget about it and move on to our next assignment. I couldn't let it go though because I needed to see it work. I am just starting out at this and we are only 5 weeks in and figured out the code I had on my own since we had not started animation yet. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: I had another question that I was wondering if you might be able to assist with. I am trying to animate a whole house that I made using JS just like this box. I don't necessarily need just the answer but I want to learn how to do it.   Reading up on SVGjs does not help me understand it all at the moment. At least check out the house I did and maybe you could point me in a direction as to some tutorials or something that would help me get a better understanding of doing the animation in particular. Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated. Thanks.https://jsfiddle.net/Jesta1972/ajsa7nav/

Comment: @Jesta1972 Personally I favor very much to delve into the specs, in this case [the W3C standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/). However, it's a matter of taste - the content at MDN usually presents the topics in a gentler way while upholding quality. There is a [tutorial about SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial) which might be a good start.

Comment: I am still working on the house you helped me with before. I was wondering if you could assist in pointing out what it is in my code that is making these lines not draw properly. I have managed to get all the rest of them to work, this one line however just either goes the wrong way or starts at the bottom and goes in reverse and no matter how I move around the numbers I can not get it to work.  https://jsfiddle.net/Jesta1972/wyrperph/